# Fade siblings on hover. jQuery to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, siblings

I have the following navigation. Upon mouseover of a link, I want the other two links' opacity to lower and return to full opacity upon mouseout.
I have accomplished this with jQuery and have found other questions/answer with a mix, but am struggling with a pure vanilla javascript solution as I do not want to use jQuery at all for this project.

HTML

```
<nav id="nav-main">
  <h1><a>Home</a></h1>
  <h1><a>About</a></h1>
  <h1><a>Contact</a></h1>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#nav-main a').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
    $this.parent().siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 0.3);
  },function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
    $this.parent().siblings().stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku9gW/)

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS3 transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/ku9gW/1/

Comment: This is what I tried originally, but I don't want the links to fade unless the actual text is being hovered.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could use Google Closure's library which compiles to pure Javascript whilst still allowing you to use library-style functions. (Unlike jQuery, Closure includes all the library machinery in the compiled code.)

Comment: I'm trying to improve my javascript, so reinventing the wheel would be better for education reasons ;)

Comment: @stagi  Good on you :)